# Setting input attributes with props and <script setup>

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

Is it possible to set a form input type using a prop?

The below does not seem to work, any others ways to do this?

For example

```js
<script setup>
defineProps({
  InputType: String,
  InputId: String,
  InputLabel: String,
  InputPlaceholder: String
});
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="ml-6 mt-5 mr-6 mb-5 lg:w-1/2">
    <label
      :for="InputId"
      class="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900"
    >
      {{ InputLabel }}
    </label>
    <div class="mt-2">
      <input
        :id="InputId"
        :type="InputType"
        class="block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-pink-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
        :placeholder="InputPlaceholder"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: How do you use the component in  parent one?

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-defineemits) on how to use props with `<script setup>`.  The value of `defineProps` must be assigned, then props will be usable in your template.

```js
const props = defineProps({
    InputType: String,
    InputId: String,
    InputLabel: String,
    InputPlaceholder: String,
})
```

```html
<label :for="props.InputId">{{ props.InputLabel }}</label>
<div class="mt-2">
  <input :type="props.InputType" :id="props.InputId" v-bind:placeholder="props.InputPlaceholder">
</div>
```

Note: props can be automatically unwrapped in your template so `InputId` can be used instead of `props.InputId`. It is only strictly necessary if used elsewhere in `<script setup>`

Comment: +1 on the assigning the props notice. But, are you sure we have to use `props.` in the template bindings? I don't think so. I bet it should be just `:type="InputType"`

Comment: You don't have to, no, I'm just being verbose for clarity.  You can do it either way

Answer (score 0):

The child component should define the props with `camelCase` names `inputLabel` instead of `InputLabel` :

```js
defineProps({
  inputType: String,
  inputId: String,
  inputLabel: String,
  inputPlaceholder: String
});
```

and they should be used in parent component like :

`<Child input-label="somee label"/>` or `<Child inputLabel="somee label"/>`

**[LIVE DEMO](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)**

Answer (score -1):

You could use a prop "type" for rendering the input base on it.

```
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
    type: {type: String, default: ''},
    formField: {type: Object, default: {}}
    }) 
<script>
    
<template>
    <div v-if="type === 'text'">
    </div>
    <div v-if="type === 'file'">
    </div>
    <div v-if="type === 'checkbox'">
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score -2):

Basic solution.

Check also [How to force a Vue component to re-render](https://blog.logrocket.com/force-vue-component-re-render/#vues-built-in-force-update-method) if you will need to reload your component.

```js
const { createApp } = Vue

const MyInput = {
  props: ['type'],
  template: 'Type: {{type}} <br/> <input :type="type" />'  
}

const App = {  
  components: {
    MyInput
  },
  data() {
    return {
      type: 'text',
      types: ['text', 'radio', 'checkbox']
    }
  },
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
 <div id="app" v-cloak>
  Type: <select v-model="type">
  <option v-for="t in types">{{t}}</option>
  </select><br/>
  <my-input :type="type"></my-input>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```